# Error when packaging an Android Project made in Unreal Engine

Tags: android, unreal-engine5

ok I’ve built an app for mobile (Android). At first everything was working perfectly. I was able to cook and install the package on my phone. But as the project get more complicated, I’m not able to build (Sent the installation to my phone) anymore. Cooking is working but not the packaging. After several test I figured that every time I install a plugin (no matter what plug in it is) I get this error:

PackagingResults: Error: Launch failed! Missing UnrealGame binary.
You may have to build the UE project with your IDE. Alternatively, build using UnrealBuildTool with the
commandline:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5dOC.png)

I tried

- Reinstalling the Engine
- Rebuild the project from scratch
- Deactivate and reactivate the plug in
- tried with different plug in (Built in or third party gave me the same error)
- Delete intermediate file
- Tried to package via different engine (4.27 , 5, 5.1 , 5.2)